# How do I make home-made Vietnamese or thai rice noodles?

Tags: noodles, vietnamese-cuisine

In Vietnam, fresh noodles are easy to find, however in Australia, the nearest substitute seems to be plain (and dry) rice vermicelli noodles, which do not have the same flavour or texture, the fresh noodles have a fresh flavour that has a subtle texture, quite unlike dried vermicelli noodles.

I want to make the perfect Vietnamese noodle, however, the first step for me is knowing the name and any suggestions that will help me obtain this noodle!

So, I would like to know what these noodles are typically called (perhaps in Viet or Thai language), and/or any tips or other suggestions that will allow me to find a recipe.

The only thing I can point out is that these are thin noodles, and are not like soba.

Comment: Hi Arafangion, according to our FAQ, recipe requests are off topic. Your question looks to me like a recipe request. If you have picked a recipe and something isn't clear or something went wrong, you certainly can ask that, since those are close-ended question.

Comment: @Mien: There are a *ton* of questions relating to noodles, just not, as best as I can tell, specifically vietnamese or thai rice noodles.  I am not asking about a recipe, but very specifically the noodle itself.  Almost everything I see says: "Soak the noodles in water", but what about making those noodles themselves? THAT is what I want to cook.  Part of the problem is that I don't actually know the proper name for these noodles... Except that they aren't Udon noodles.

Comment: "There are a *ton* of questions relating to noodles...I am not asking about a recipe, but very specifically the noodle itself." You *are* asking for a recipe - one for the noodles themselves. And all the other questions about noodles are not asking for recipes. Maybe you should be asking about the names of the kinds of noodles you want to make (and including more of a description of what you're looking for), so that you can go out and find recipes. You're also welcome to hop into [chat] to discuss any of this!

Comment: @jefromi: I suppose you're right, thanks for the suggestions!

Comment: Also, you might be interested in searching on youtube for "handmade vietnamese noodles" to get an idea of the way they're made.

Comment: @Jefromi: I've looked at those, they look similar, however those videos seem to be flour-based, however I am sure the ones I am thinking of are rice-based.  I have to get to bed, it might be worth closing this question until I have done some more research, however your suggestions have been very helpful.

Comment: In any case, I believe Vietnamese rice noodles are made using a laborious involving pounding rice for hours; probably not something you can do at home.

Answer (score 3):

Are you asking about [Bánh Phở](http://www.lovingpho.com/pho-ingredients-garnishes/banh-pho-noodles/)?

Comment: Yes, that's it!!

Comment: Ok, after some research, I want to know if it's *possible* to make this at home, or if it is seriously far too much effort. :(

Comment: I don't actually know anyone that makes their own bánh phở -- and my family is Vietnamese. I've mostly seen people use the dry versions (which are very cheap and easily found at any asian market). I would try these first before going through the effort of making your own. What are you planning to use them for anyways?

Comment: For pho, mostly, but also for a vaguely-thai noodle dish that we like as well - they have this sweet, vinegary noodle dish that has chilli, some kind of vinegar/lime lotus, generally delicious. That would also be good to recreate.  I have some friends who have gotten used to authentic vietnamese food and they want to have it again.

Comment: In case of link rot (as one of the videos in the link is already unavailable) -- rice was soaked in water overnight, then blended with potato starch and water;  It was then spread on tightly stretched cloth over a steamer and cooked for about 30 seconds.  It was then peeled off and placed on a bamboo mat to dry in the sun for 5-6 hrs before being cut into noodles.  So *technically* possible, but only at a smaller scale (unless you have a 30" / 75cm wide steamer).

Answer (score -3):

To make noodle like Vietnamese, it is not so difficult.
You need to put the rice into the water for few hours, grin the portion you prefer.
The important thing, you need a steam spot with a page of silk on the top so that the steam go es up from the spot to the surface of the silk, cooking the noodle.

### Actually, making noodle needs more visual material than reading, it is more effective

[Vietnam Tours](http://www.vietnamtour.co.uk) - promote the cuisine of Vietnam